# Understanding EF Core row/table locks and isolation

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database, locking

I am working on an exhibit booth reservation system for a conference. This works similarly to concert tickets. Basically, each booth can be reserved by a user. I am using Entity Framework Core, and inside my logic to purchase a booth, I want to make sure no one else can read or write while I am in this transaction in the most performant way.

I have been reading up about isolation levels and table hits but I am a bit confused on what I need to do in this case. I THINK I want `Serializable` isolation level, but I'm not sure. What about `UPDLOCK`, `ROWLOCK` query hints?

Basically, I want this block of code below to only be able to run if no one else is updating the record inside this method. Reads should be blocked in this method too, but not in other places where I query this table.

```
   var tx = await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable);
   var product = await context.SponsorshipProducts.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == productId);
   product.Purchase(); //check to see if booth has been purchased already. If it is not, mark purchased to block other purchases.
   await context.SaveChangesAsync();
   tx.Commit();
```

This table has a `ReservedById` column which indicates if the exhibit has been reserved. I want to make sure this can only be updated by one user at a time for a given record.

Comment: Transaction isolation levels and row/table locks are **NOT** part of EF Core - but part of the **underlying database engine** - so this all depends on what concrete **RDBMS** you're using (and accessing it with EF Core). SQL Server or PostgreSQL or Oracle will all have different strategies and settings to handle all those things.....

Comment: Hey @marc_s thanks for the note. This is running against SQL Azure, so READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT is on ON

Comment: Maybe it is better to do not block table but use [Concurrency Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations)? Who is first, will reserve conference, other [will fail with DbUpdateConcurrencyException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency)

Answer (score 0):

There are typically four types of Isolation Levels:

- **Read uncommitted (lowest level)**
  In this isolation level we can read data before it is committed by operation.
- **Read committed (default Isolation Level)**
  In this isolation level we can read data only after it is committed by operation.
- **Repeatable Read**
  In this isolation level it reads and lock it until the operation gets over.
- **Serializable (highest level)**
  Serializable is very similar to repeatable read Isolation Level but in this isolation level it will not allow not add new data during the transaction.

> I want this block of code below to only be able to run if no one else is updating the record inside this method. Reads should be blocked in this method too, but not in other places where I query this table.

for this scenario Serializable or Repeatable Read Isolation level can applicable.

for more information you can refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.isolationlevel?view=net-6.0).

Answer (score 0):

I was needing a simpel solution to lock 1 row in a table.

I use this:

```
public class LockTable
{
    public LockTable(string lockKeyId)
    {
        LockKeyId = lockKeyId;
        CreateAt = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [Key]
    public string LockKeyId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateAt { get; set; }
}

    public async Task<bool> UpdateDataAsyncLock(TestTable input, string rowKey)
    {
        // Check if row is lock
        LockTable? temp = await context.LockTable.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.LockKeyId == rowKey);
        bool res = false;

        if (temp == null)
        {
            // No lock -> do work
            temp = new LockTable(rowKey);

            try
            {
                // lock row
                await context.LockTable.AddAsync(temp);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();

                // Row lock, Update data
                res = await UpdateTestDataAsync(input);

                // Remove row lock
                context.LockTable.Remove(temp);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();                    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Dubplicate Primary Key, no update possible.
                // some one have made an insert in while code is running. (Shut not happening...)
            }
        }

        // Remove all lock that are 10 min or old. Do we need this?
        await CleanUpLocks();
        return res;
    }

    private async Task<bool> UpdateTestDataAsync(TestTable input)
    {
        TestTable? temp = await context.TestTable.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.PublicId == input.PublicId);
        bool res = false;

        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp.ChangesCounter++;
            temp.ValueToUpdate = input.ValueToUpdate;
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            res = true;
        }
        return res;
    }

    public async Task CleanUpLocks()
    {
        // Delete stuff that are 10 min old. There shut be nothing to delete happening...
        DateTime timeOut = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10);
        List<LockTable> toDelete = await context.LockTable.Where(x => x.CreateAt <= timeOut).ToListAsync();

        context.LockTable.RemoveRange(toDelete);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

To make the code reusable it can be done like this:

```
public class DataBase
 {
     public async virtual Task<bool> UpdateDate()
     {
         return false;
     }
 }

public class PersonUpdate : DataBase
{
    public TestTable testTable;
    public PersonUpdate(TestTable input)
    {
        testTable = input;
    }

    public override async Task<bool> UpdateDate()
    {
        DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext();
        TestTable? temp = await context.TestTable.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.PublicId == testTable.PublicId);
        bool res = false;

        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp.ChangesCounter++;
            temp.ValueToUpdate = testTable.ValueToUpdate;
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            res = true;
        }
        return res;
    }
}

 public async Task<bool> UpdateDataAsyncLock(DataBase input, string rowKey)
 {
     // Check if row is lock
     LockTable? temp = await context.LockTable.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.LockKeyId == rowKey);
     bool res = false;

     if (temp == null)
     {
         // No lock -> do work
         temp = new LockTable(rowKey);

         try
         {
             // lock row
             await context.LockTable.AddAsync(temp);
             await context.SaveChangesAsync();

             // Row lock, Update data
             res = await input.UpdateDate();

             // Remove row lock
             context.LockTable.Remove(temp);
             await context.SaveChangesAsync();                    
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             // Dubplicate Primary Key, no update possible.
             // some one have made an insert in while code is running. (Shut not happening...)
         }
     }

     // Remove all lock that are 10 min or old. Do we need this?
     await CleanUpLocks();
     return res;
 }
```